# ошибка в json файле

Tags: python, json, discord.py

есть файл json:

```
    "info": {
        "guilds": [{           
            "guild": {
                "id": 926850130039148554,
                "name": "v1la | server",
                "user": 55,
                "members": 53,
                "bots": 2,
                "roles": {
                    "mute": 927842918851563520,
                    "voice_create": 927842909343064115,
                    "new_role": 927181380109074492
                },
                "channels": {
                    "voice_mod": 927255226371698758,
                    "join": 927340216761585675,
                    "leave": 927340302006636614
                }
            }
        }, {           
            "guild": {
                "id": 821277749905195019,
                "name": "AnimEsHnik | clan",
                "user": 30,
                "members": 27,
                "bots": 3,
                "roles": {
                    "mute": 935937798614155294,
                    "voice_create": 929388475160096769,
                    "new_role": 929349231792246784
                },
                "channels": {
                    "voice_mod": 929392137135611984,
                    "join": 929379756888195093,
                    "leave": 929379792422305864
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

при попытке вывести name данным кодом:

```
jjj = """
{
    "info": {
        "guilds": [{           
            "guild": {
                "id": 926850130039148554,
                "name": "v1la | server",
                "user": 55,
                "members": 53,
                "bots": 2,
                "roles": {
                    "mute": 927842918851563520,
                    "voice_create": 927842909343064115,
                    "new_role": 927181380109074492
                },
                "channels": {
                    "voice_mod": 927255226371698758,
                    "join": 927340216761585675,
                    "leave": 927340302006636614
                }
            }
        }, {           
            "guild": {
                "id": 821277749905195019,
                "name": "AnimEsHnik | clan",
                "user": 30,
                "members": 27,
                "bots": 3,
                "roles": {
                    "mute": 935937798614155294,
                    "voice_create": 929388475160096769,
                    "new_role": 929349231792246784
                },
                "channels": {
                    "voice_mod": 929392137135611984,
                    "join": 929379756888195093,
                    "leave": 929379792422305864
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}"""
print(type(jjj))
data = json.loads(jjj)
for guild in data['info']['guilds']['guild']:
    print(guild['name'])
```

вылазит ошибка:
for guild in data['info']['guilds']['guild']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

что делать????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас `data['info']['guilds']` - это список. Поэтому питон и говорит, что к списку можно обращаться только по целочисленным ключам.

Поэтому вам нужно что-то в стиле

```
for guild_wrapper in data['info']['guilds']:
  guild = guild_wrapper['guild']
```

Comment: cпасибо большое!